# R Markdown and Latex preamble; how do I get non-evaluated code blocks and evaluated code blocks to look the same?

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I have a new R package I'm developing for a set of R Markdown templates [among other things] to get all our analytics departments aligned with the same style for reports. I've created a new `preamble.tex` file and have successfully gotten it to apply to the knitted document. My problem comes with code blocks and, what I assume to be, the `verbatim` environment.

Code blocks which are not evaluated, or for which no language has been specified, correctly show line numbering as defined in the `preamble` below. Code blocks which **are** evaluated, however, do not have the line numbers displayed.

[Current output with different formats for evaluated and non-evaluated code chunks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EunO8.png)

My question is, then, why? And what do I need to do to my `preamble` to get both evaluated [and, therefore highlighted] code and non-evaluated code to have the line numbers included? I also notice that the shaded environment for evaluated code doesn't have the same before and after spacing as the non-evaluated code, and I have no idea why.

To be clear: I wouldn't even consider myself a newbie at latex. I have no idea what I'm actually doing, but it's mostly been working.

The relevant parts of my `preamble.tex` are included below, along with a MWE `.Rmd` document.

**Latex Preamble:**

```
% Load required LaTeX packages
\usepackage{xcolor} % Color and color definitions
\usepackage{framed} % Package for block quote styling
\usepackage{fancyvrb}   % Package for code block styling

% Define Color Palette
\definecolor{mpsyellow}{RGB}{253,184,19}
\definecolor{mpswine}{RGB}{133,12,112}
\definecolor{mpsdarkblue}{RGB}{0,101,164}

% Block Quotes Defined
\let\oldquote=\quote
\let\endoldquote=\endquote
\renewenvironment{quote}{
    \colorlet{shadecolor}{mpswine!10}
    \begin{shaded*}
    \begin{oldquote}\itshape%
}{%
    \end{oldquote}%
    \end{shaded*}%
}

% Code Block Quotes Defined
\renewenvironment{verbatim}{%
    \VerbatimEnvironment
    \colorlet{shadecolor}{mpsyellow!5}
    \begin{shaded*}
    \begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,xleftmargin=5mm]%
}{%
    \end{Verbatim}%
    \end{shaded*}%
}
```

**R Markdown:**

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "author"
date: 'r Sys.Date()'
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: lualatex
header-includes:
  - \input{preamble.tex}
---

## R Code Chunk:
```{r demo_chunk, echo=TRUE}
summary(mtcars$mpg)
```

## Block Quote:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed tincidunt 
> urna. Sed scelerisque sit amet nunc et maximus. Maecenas et posuere quam. 
> Pellentesque aliquam volutpat auctor. Duis non neque luctus felis varius 
> vehicula at quis mi. Etiam sed sem neque. Nam odio nulla, suscipit eu erat non, 
> feugiat posuere massa.

## Non-evaluated code blocks:
```
summary(mtcars$mpg)
```

## Inline Code
You can use `scale_color_mps()` with your plots now!
````